# Facebook login button in Android returns user to the same page after logging in

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook, android-fragments

I currently have a Facebook login button in my main activity and want the user to view a new fragment after logging in. However, as it stands, the user gets taken back to the main activity after logging in and I'm not sure why. I defined the button in XML:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        facebook:com_facebook_login_text="FACEBOOK"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

and in my MainActivity in `onCreate()` I initialised the button:

```
fbLogIn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
fbLogIn.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
fbLogIn.registerCallback(FbFragment.mCallBackManager, FbFragment.mCallBack);
```

FbFragment is the Fragment I want the user to be taken to after logging in via the button - and it contains stuff like the CallbackManager:

```
public class FbFragment extends Fragment {
    private static TextView mTextDetails;
    public static CallbackManager mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();;
    public static FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why this Fragment never gets displayed. Out of desperation I even tried setting up an onClickListener() in MainActivity where FbFragment gets initialised every time the button gets clicked but that didn't work either (unsurprisingly).

Any ideas? Highly grateful for any help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you are getting callback in onActivityResult() in your FbFragment Please check it and tell if any exception thrown..

Comment: Hey, how can I check this?

Comment: Ok turns out you are right - it never gets called. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: you can destroy your fragment and get result in your activity 

`public static FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
// Destroy Fragment Here 
onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        }
    };
`

Comment: Ah nice, moving everything over from the fragment class to the main activity worked. However, the problem I have now is that if a user is already logged into facebook the button says "Log out" rather than "Log in with Facebook". Do you know how I can stop this from happening? I need  it to say Log in so that you get directed to the home page after logging in, then you should be able to log out from there.

Comment: you need to deploy facebook login button in the activity also it will turn into logout button automatically after successful login

Answer (score 0):

This is an activity for facebook login :- **HOPE THIS HELPS !!!**

```
public class FacebookActivity extends BaseActivity {

private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private ImageView cancelBtn, iv_googlePlus, loginBtn;
private String accessToken;
private String android_id = "";
private TextView tv_letsFrndOnFb,tv_knowYouBetter,tv_and,tv_serveYouBetter,tv_willNotPost;

private Context FbContext = FacebookActivity.this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

    iv_googlePlus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_googlePlus);
    tv_letsFrndOnFb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_letsFrndOnFb);
    tv_knowYouBetter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_knowYouBetter);
    tv_and = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_and);
    tv_serveYouBetter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_serveYouBetter);
    tv_willNotPost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_willNotPost);
    tv_letsFrndOnFb.setTypeface(PACIFICO);
    tv_knowYouBetter.setTypeface(PROXIMA_NOVA_BOLD);
    tv_and.setTypeface(PROXIMA_NOVA_LIGHT_ITALIK);
    tv_serveYouBetter.setTypeface(PROXIMA_NOVA_BOLD);
    tv_willNotPost.setTypeface(PROXIMA_NOVA_LIGHT);

    cancelBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_cancelBtn);
    loginBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_checkBtn);

    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(FacebookActivity.this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.d(TAG,"DEVICE_ID : "+android_id);

    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookActivity.this, NumberVerifyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            FacebookActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
                fbLogin();
            } else
                displayToast(R.string.need_network);
        }
    });
}

public void fbLogin() {
    Session.openActiveSession(FacebookActivity.this, true,
            new Session.StatusCallback() {

                // callback when session changes state
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                                 Exception exception) {

                    Log.v(TAG, "APP ID : " + session.getApplicationId());

                    accessToken = session.getAccessToken();

                    Log.v(TAG, "ACCESS TOKEN : " + accessToken);
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "SESSION STATE : " + "Active");
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                                            Response response) {

                                        System.out.println(TAG
                                                + "FACEBOOK RESPONSE : "
                                                + response.toString());
                                        GraphObject go = response
                                                .getGraphObject();
                                        go.getProperty("gender");
                                        System.out.println(TAG
                                                + "USER GENDER : "
                                                + go.getProperty("gender"));
                                        if (user != null) {
                                            System.out.println(TAG
                                                    + "USER NAME : "
                                                    + user.getName());
                                            System.out.println(TAG
                                                    + "USER FACEBOOK ID : "
                                                    + user.getId());
                                            System.out.println(TAG
                                                    + "USER FIRST NAME : "
                                                    + user.getFirstName());
                                            System.out.println(TAG
                                                    + "USER LAST NAME : "
                                                    + user.getLastName());
                                            System.out.println(TAG
                                                    + "USER DOB : "
                                                    + user.getBirthday());
                                              if(user.getName()!=null && go.getProperty("gender")!=null && user.getId()!=null){


                                            if(user.getName()!=null && go.getProperty("gender")!=null && user.getId()!=null){
                                                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                                b.putString("Gender", go.getProperty("gender").toString());
                                                Intent i = new Intent(FacebookActivity.this,NumberVerifyActivity.class);
                                                i.putExtras(b);
                                                startActivity(i);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```